# How to find max values?

Tags: python

I need to find max of values for example:

```
[(12, 0.95), (15, 0.92), (20, 0.90), (12, 0.88), (15, 0.98), (12, 0.89)]
```

Output will max value corresponds with the id:

```
[(12, 0.95), (15, 0.98), (20, 0.90)]
```

How can I achieve this in python?

Any suggestions! Thanks for the help

Comment: What have you tried thus far? What attempts have you made in solving the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just the basics:

```
data = [(12, 0.95), (15, 0.92), (20, 0.90), (12, 0.88), (15, 0.98), (12, 0.89)]

result_dict = {}
for id_num, value in data:
    result_dict[id_num] = max(value, result_dict.get(id_num, value))

result = sorted(result_dict.items())

print(result)
```

If the part inside the loop is confusing, here are other ways to write it:

```
if id_num in result_dict:
    result_dict[id_num] = max(result_dict[id_num], value)
else:
    result_dict[id_num] = value
```

or

```
if id_num in result_dict:
    if value > result_dict[id_num]:
        result_dict[id_num] = value
else:
    result_dict[id_num] = value
```

or

```
if id_num not in result_dict or value > result_dict[id_num]:
    result_dict[id_num] = value
```

or

```
if id_num > result_dict.get(id_num, value):
    result_dict[id_num] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort, `groupby`, and `max`!

```
import itertools
import operator

data = [(12, 0.95), (15, 0.92), (20, 0.90), (12, 0.88), (15, 0.98), (12, 0.89)]
sorted_data = sorted(data)
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted_data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
result = [max(group) for _, group in groups]
```

`itertools.groupby` takes a sorted list of items, groups them by some key function (in this case we use `operator.itemgetter(0)`), and gives you an iterator of the form:

```
[(keyfunc_result, [list_of_results...], ... ]
```

Comment: This gives the wrong result, you need to add a key to `groupby`. The default key is the identity so all the groups have 0 elements because they're all distinct.

Comment: Shoot you're right, I thought it defaulted to `itemgetter(0)`. Sec

Comment: @AlexHall fixed

Comment: note that the sort has already moved the max to the last item of each group